# More than one record has been inserted when i want to insert only one

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I want to execute a procedure that insert data in a table
when I execute the procedure it insert more than one record with the same data and different id
I tried to create trigger but doesn't work correctly
anyone can help me?

Comment: Please show us your code, what you have tried, and what the desired outcome is.

Comment: It is quite difficult to debug code you can't see. As you tagged question with Apex tag, it seems that process fires more than once; maybe for each row in an interactive grid, or something like that? Basically, we have too few info to suggest *anything* useful.